# How can i create custom tabs in BigCommerce

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I am trying to create custom tabs in BigCommerce but didn't come across any satisfactory solution.

Here is the format of product page in which i am already getting this default tabs

- Product Description
- Warranty
- Reviews
- Other Details

I want a dynamic tab for **Q&A** section for a specific product.

I am aware that it can be done through the script but not able to find it. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Here is how to create custom tabs: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/dynamic-content#tabs

Answer (score 2):

You can use the {{split}} handlebars helper to split your product description content into sections that should be displayed on different tabs.

For example, you could edit your description-tabs.html file (or the equivalent file if you are using a theme other than Cornerstone) like this to add the new tab and split the product description content into two sections:

```
<ul class="tabs" data-tab>
    <li class="tab is-active">
        <a class="tab-title" href="#tab-description">{{lang 'products.description'}}</a>
    </li>
    {{#if product.warranty}}
        <li class="tab">
            <a class="tab-title" href="#tab-warranty">{{lang 'products.warranty'}}</a>
        </li>
    {{/if}}
    <li class="tab">
            <a class="tab-title" href="#tab-faq">Q & A</a>
        </li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs-contents">
    <div class="tab-content is-active" id="tab-description">
        {{{first (split product.description '<!-- tab -->')}}}
    </div>
   {{#if product.warranty}}
       <div class="tab-content" id="tab-warranty">
           {{{product.warranty}}}
       </div>
   {{/if}}
   <div class="tab-content" id="tab-faq">
           {{{last (split product.description '<!-- tab -->')}}}
       </div>
</div>
```

The delimiter we're specifying is `<!-- tab -->`. To divide your description content among different tabs, enter your product description and your Q&A section into the product description editor with `<!-- tab -->` in between the sections to indicate where the content should be split among different tabs.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer works however don't use `'<!-- tab -->'` it compiles as `&lt;!-- tab --&#62;` in source code so it will not work. Use any string with normal characters. Ex: `'splity'`